# Python - change numpy (int) array to HH:MM

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get my code to take times in the 24hr format (such as 0930 (09:30 AM) or 20h45 (08:45 PM)) and output it as 09:30 and 20:45, respectively.

I tried using `datetime` and `strftime`, etc., but I can't use it on Numpy arrays.

I've also tried formatting as Numpy datetime, but I can't seem to get the HH:MM format.

This is my array (example)

`[0845 0925 1046 2042 2153]`

and I would like to output this:

`[08:45 09:25 10:46 20:42 21:53]`

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What's the code that's producing that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to acomplish, I think this is the desired output.

For parsing dates you should first use "strptime" to get a datetime object and then "strftime" to get it back into desired string.

You are saying you got numpy arrays, but u got leading zeroes in this example you gave, so I guess it is an np array with defined string dytpe.

Custom functions can be vectorized to work on numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


a=np.array(["0845", "0925", "1046", "2042", "2153"],dtype = str)

def fun(x):
    x=datetime.strptime(x,"%H%M")
    return datetime.strftime(x,"%H:%M")

vfunc = np.vectorize(fun)

result = vfunc(a)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer that ended up working. Helped a lot. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, if that's what OP wanted involving `datetime` seems like a huge overkill. How about `fun = lambda x: f"{x[:2]}:{x[2:]}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `pandas.to_datetime()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array(["0845","0925","1046","2042","2153"])

y = pd.to_datetime(x, format="%H%M").to_numpy()
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> x

['0845' '0925' '1046' '2042' '2153']

>>> y

['1900-01-01T08:45:00.000000000' '1900-01-01T09:25:00.000000000'
 '1900-01-01T10:46:00.000000000' '1900-01-01T20:42:00.000000000'
 '1900-01-01T21:53:00.000000000']
```

More info:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the initial array includes only valid values (eg. values like '08453' or '2500' are not valid), this is a simple solution that does not require importing extra modules:

```
import numpy

arr = numpy.array(["0845","0925","1046","2042","2153"])
new_arr = []
for x in arr:
    elem = x[:2] + ":" + x[2:]
    new_arr.append(elem)
print(new_arr)
```